# How to approach the sorting based algorithm/ undertstanding the intuition behind the code?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have been stuck on an algorithm problem, I need help to make progress with it. The problem statement is as follows.

### **Problem definition:**

**There are `2N` people a company is planning to interview. The cost of flying the `i-th` person to city `A` is `costs[i][0]`, and the cost of flying the `i-th` person to city `B` is `costs[i][1]`.**

**Return the minimum cost to fly every person to a city such that exactly `N` people arrive in each city.**

Input: `[[10,20],[30,200],[400,50],[30,20]]`

Output: `110`

I have seen a few solutions and they involve sorting.

However, I am not able to get the intuition.

Can somebody explain to me how to go about solving this problem?

Here is sample solution that I found:

```
    public int twoCitySchedCost(int[][] costs) {
        Comparator<int[]> comparator = (a, b) -> Math.abs(b[0] - b[1]) - Math.abs(a[0] - a[1]);
        Arrays.sort(costs, comparator);
        int N = costs.length / 2,
                c1 = 0,// counter for the station A
                c2 = 0,// counter for the station B
                ans = 0,
                i = 0;
        while (i < 2 * N) {
            if ((costs[i][0] <= costs[i][1] && c1 < N) || c2 == N) {
                ans += costs[i++][0];
                c1++;
            } else {
                ans += costs[i++][1];
                c2++;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's first go over what this algorithm is doing. It is sorting each person based on the difference between their cost of going to city A versus city B. For example, if person X had costs 1 and 100 of going to city A and B respectively, and person Y had costs 49 and 50 of going to city A and B respectively, then person X would come earlier in the sorted order than person Y. I would try plugging in a few examples into the comparator to realize this.

Next, the algorithm *greedily* (meaning without needing foresight to later people) gives each person their cheaper city in the order of the sorted list. This continues until one city is "full" i.e. has N people assigned to it at which point everyone else is just assigned to the other city. This happens in the while loop and two conditional statements. Can you see how this logic is playing out?

Finally, it begs the question why this solution is valid. Note that if we took away the constraint that each city must have N people going to it, then the best solution would of course be to send each person to their cheaper city. However, given this limitation, this is not always possible. Each time someone does not visit their minimum cost city, they deviate from the minimum solution of having everyone go to their cheaper city. Namely, they deviate by exactly the absolute value of the difference in costs between city A and city B. As a result, it makes sense that we consider giving those people that have a large difference in cost their first choice (otherwise, if they have to deviate, the change in cost will be the largest for them). As a result, this is why we greedily consider the people in this sorted order.